How to resolve python iterpreter-related "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch’” on a Mac
I have cleanly and successfully installed PyTorch and associated packages within my virtual environment (BotVirtualEnv). It passed all required tests, including that of Python Interpreter and ensured it's selected within VSCode. In my neural_net.py script I created the following import statements (import torch, import torch.nn as nn, import torch.optim as optim) with which to work. The code itself is clean with no syntactic errors, yet the interpreter keeps throwing the below error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sBliss_/Trading-Algorithm/src/neural_net.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'

I am here only because I have exhausted every troubleshooting knowledge that I have. I even created an environment variable and pointed the interpreter to it as well, and all to NO avail. Someone please help.

Are you sure that you are running this code inside your virtual environment? If Python cannot find the module then it is most likely that you are not.

OldBoy, thanx for your response. The answer to your question is a definite YES. Please see below:
/Users/sBliss_/Trading-Algorithm/BotVirtualEnv/bin/python /Users/sBliss_/Trading-Algorithm/src/neural_net.py
/Users/sBliss_/Trading-Algorithm/BotVirtualEnv/bin/python /Users/sBliss_/Trading-Algorithm/src/neural_net.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/sBliss_/Trading-Algorithm/src/neural_net.py", line 1, in 
import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'

Well it is clear that one of these is the answer: 1. You have not activated the virtual environment where torch is installed. or 2. You have activated it, but you installed torch somewhere else. Please update your question with a folder list showing where torch is installed, and an execution of the program starting with the command that activates the virtual environment.

SFN_ source /Users/sBliss_/Trading-Algorithm/BotVirtualEnv/bin/activate
(BotVirEnv) SFN_ pip3 list
Package                       Version

torch                         2.2.2
torchaudio                    2.2.2
torchvision                   0.17.2
tornado                       6.2
(BotVirEnv) SFN_ pip3 show torch
Name: torch
Version: 2.2.2
Summary: Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration
Homepage: https://pytorch.org/
Author: PyTorch Team. Text abbreviated for space constraints.

That output is different from the previous post, and your question. Can you please update your question (using the Edit link) with the complete details from calling activate to actually trying to run the code?


The outputs (a) "source /Users/sBliss_/Trading-Algorithm/BotVirtualEnv/bin/activate" was used to activate the venv (BotVirtualEnv), and then (b) used "pip3 list" to list ALL installed packages that include torch, torchvision, and torchaudio. In that output you referenced, if you noticed, it was supposed to look something like: (BotVirEnv) SFN_ pip3 list. Translations: 1. (BotVirEnv) = inside the venv. 2. SFN_ = command prompt. 3. pip3 list = list all installed packages within the venv. Please be advised that I have ulterior motive with this breakdown. It's only to show the installation.


Here is the location information as well. SFN_ python3
Python 3.11.2 (v3.11.2:878ead1ac1, Feb  7 2023, 10:02:41) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.



import torch
print(torch.file)
/Users/sBliss_/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/torch/init.py




The Question: "How to resolve Python interpreter- related ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'" on a Mac? Please let me know if this is not the question you're asking to know, thanx.
